# Cambiar el Controlador por defecto de Symfony

Tags: symfony3

*Symfony* al cargar los archivos me carga el controlador por defecto, **DefaultController.php**. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar ese archivo por cualquier otro nombre?

Lógicamente el error que me sale al eliminarlo es:

> class AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController does no exist

Comment: Ya checaste el archivo `/app/config/routing.yml`

Comment: Si ya revise el archivo la verdad intente probando a modificarlo pero me sigue pidiendo el archivo DefaultController.php. Ademas baje otro proyecto en GitHub y la configuracion de routing.yml estaba identica y no tenia el DefaultController de Controlador

Comment: checa este link te puede servir https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-symfony2-route-annotations/

Answer (score 1):

Tanto el nombre del archivo como el nombre de la clase deben ser idénticos:

```
AppBundle\Controller\[Nombre]Controller || AppBundle\Controller\[Nombre]Controller.php
//                   ^^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

Si usas routing.yml:

```
app:
    path:     /usuarios
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:[Nombre]:usuarios" }
```